# how to shortlist objects in ModelForm foreign key field based upon in put

Tags: django, django-forms

i need to shortlist Players from a specific team when i am entering a shortlisted players for a particuar match. my form field gives me a list of all players. I followed this to the letter

http://www.wkoorts.com/wkblog/2009/08/10/pre-populate-django-modelform-with-specific-queryset/

but it gives me attribute error. Here is my code forms.py

```
class ShortlistForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PlayerShortlist
        fields = (
            'player',
        )
```

and my view.py

```
def shortlist(request, team_id, fixture_id):
    template = get_template('cricket/shortlist.html')
    loggedinuser = request.user
    userteam = Team.objects.get(owner=loggedinuser)
    form = ShortlistForm
    #get the players only belonging to this team_id
    form.fields['player'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team=userteam)
    currentteam = Team.objects.get(id=team_id)
    page_vars = Context({
        'form': form,
        'loggedinuser': loggedinuser,
        'team': userteam
    })
    output = template.render(page_vars)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

if i remove the line

```
form.fields['player'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team=userteam)
```

it gives me this error.

```
AttributeError at /team/1/fixture/1/shortlist/
type object 'ShortlistForm' has no attribute 'fields'
```

what i am i doing wrong?

//mouse

and while we are at it, if i can list all the players with accompnying check boxes, to be put in the database, rather boss have a dropdown .. what should i choose from the formset?

//mouse

again, solved it myself.

need to initiate form first.

```
form = ShortlistForm
```

should be

```
form = ShortlistForm()
```

//mouse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite a bit here:

1. Why are you assigning `request.user` to `loggedinuser`? It's exactly the same amount of keystrokes, so you aren't saving yourself anything and only abstracting logic and adding points of failure to your code.
2. When assigning the `form` you're assigning the *class*, not an instance of that class. You need instead:

   ```
   form = ShortlistForm()
   ```
3. When defining `currentteam` you need to catch the possibility of an incorrect `team_id` being passed in. The easiest way is with `get_object_or_404`:

   ```
   currentteam = get_object_or_404(Team, id=team_id)
   ```
4. Unless `Team.owner` is a `OneToOneField`, you're going to run into issues with `Team.owner.get(owner=loggedinuser)`. It's also confusing as to why you're fetching two different teams here. If you just want to filter `Players` to those that belong to teams that belong to the current user, the following is far more simplistic and safer:

   ```
   Player.objects.filter(team__owner=request.user)
   ```
5. However, why you're doing this makes no sense. The comment you have says it should be filtered for the current `team_id`, and that makes sense based on the URL containing a `team_id` parameter. I'm assuming you're simply wanting to filter by the current team but also want to make sure that that team is owned by the logged in user (user has rights to it). If that's the case, the following is what you actually need:

   ```
   team = get_object_or_404(Team, id=team_id, owner=request.user)
   ...
   Player.objects.filter(team=team)
   ```
6. The whole bit with fetching your template, rendering it, and returning the response all manually, is unnecessary and amounts to code bloat. Just do:

   ```
   # Django 1.3+
   return render(request, 'cricket/shortlist.html', page_vars)
   ```

   OR

   ```
   # Django <1.3
   return render_to_response('cricket/shortlist.html', page_vars, RequestContext(request))
   ```

   Make `page_vars` a regular old dictionary, instead of an instance of `Context`, in that scenario. This also has the benefit of bring `request` into your template context, so you can use `request.user` there as well, instead of having to pass in `loggedinuser`.

So, with that, here's your new view:

```
def shortlist(request, team_id, fixture_id):
    team = get_object_or_404(Team, id=team_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ShortlistForm(request.POST)
        #get the players only belonging to this team_id
        form.fields['player'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team=team)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/path/to/next/view/')
    else:
        form = ShortListForm()
        #get the players only belonging to this team_id
        form.fields['player'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team=team)

    return render(request, 'cricket/shortlist.html', {
        'form': form,
        'team': team,
    })
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `len(request.POST)` instead of `request.method == 'POST'`?

Comment: @roam: Old habit is all. The docs actually do recommend using `request.method=='POST'` so I'll change it.